# Firefox error - document.all is undefined (WebUIValidation.js)

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have created a simple ASP.Net application, where first page accepts an input and button click redirects the user to next page.
This is working in all the other browsers (IE, Opera, Safari), but nothing is happening in Firefox. There is no event generated on button click and no postback is happening.

A look into Firefox's error console showed me this error:

> document.all is undefined
>   http://xxx/aspnet_client/system_web/2_0_50727/WebUIValidation.js
>   Line: 30
>   Line: 85

The functions where this error is encountered in WebUIValidation.js are:

```
function ValidatorHookupControlID(controlID, val) {
    if (typeof(controlID) != "string") {
        return;
    }
    var ctrl = document.all[controlID];
```

....

```
function ValidatorGetValue(id) {
    var control;
    control = document.all[id];
```

....

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your web.config `<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>` and reading [this blog post](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/rbirkby/archive/2006/11/01/Client_2D00_side-validation-in-Firefox.aspx) for additional information on how/when client side validators are added to the page.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I got the solution. The issue was because of validation controls on the page. I made EnableClientScript property of validators to false.

Comment: Khushboo, you should add your answer as a reply and choose it as the answer.  So the next person having a similar problem, knows how you fixed it.  Thanks for sharing your fix!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code to use document.getElementById instead of document.all, like

```
function ValidatorHookupControlID(controlID, val) {
    if (typeof(controlID) != "string") {
        return;
    }
    var ctrl = document.getElementById(controlID);
    //.....
}
```

and...

```
function ValidatorGetValue(id) {
    var control = document.getElementById(id);
    //.....
}
```