# JavaScript code working on old server, but not on new

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis

This has been driving me crazy.  I'm trying to migrate some legacy applications to a new server and I'm having a lot of problems with `document.all` being peppered throughout the code.

Before you say it, I know. Don't use `document.all`.  It's there and there's nothing I can do about it...this particular problem has JavaScript within an assembly for which I do not have the source code and I don't have permission to redevelop.

My main confusion is that the current version of the application is working when I test in the same browser as my migrated version.  It's a straight copy and paste job and no code has changed during the migration, but when I run the app on the new server `document.all(element)` always returns null.

Does IIS or newer .NET frameworks somehow handle client-side scripts differently?

I'm coming from .NET 2.0 hosted on Windows Server 2005 with IIS 6, and going to .NET 4.0 hosted on Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.

I'm looking for ANY idea why these would be behaving differently when tested in the same browser

UPDATE:
A user control being targeted by `document.all` is getting encoded which is messing up the ID of the control, i.e. what should be `'elementId'` is being outputted as `&#39;elementId&#39;`

The code in the assembly is using Attributes.Add which is including single quotes.  I've found a number sources suggesting a new class such as:

```
public class HtmlAttributeEncodingNot : System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder
{
    protected override void HtmlAttributeEncode(string value, System.IO.TextWriter output)
    {
        output.Write(value);
    }
}
```

being added which will allow encoding to be turned off by using `<httpRuntime encoderType="HtmlAttributeEncodingNot"/>` in the web.config, but I am not able to add new classes to this project

Comment: Check how you have declare the `DOCTYPE` on top of your pages

Comment: It's set to `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >`

Comment: Possibly this could help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488579/firefox-error-document-all-is-undefined-webuivalidation-js

Comment: @Digitalfront my pages already contain the `<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>` tag and there are no validation controls present

Comment: The bottom line is the HTML/JS that the browser is working with - use a diff tool to compare the browser view source generated by the old and new server.  It's possible that the HTML is slightly different, or the browser is running in a different mode perhaps.

Comment: Also, a possible server side agitant is this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx

Comment: @JimW upon closer inspection it appears that the HTML is slightly different, updating my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your project is ending it's life and you just want to breath new life in to it.  I think document.all is done as of IE11, isn't it - so the clock is ticking.

What I'd suggest is writing some Javascript to iterate the DOM and look for any encoded IDs - then change those back to the .NET 2 form.  Run that JS at the bottom of the page (as opposed to onload) and hopefully nothing will have tried to access document.all before you 'correct' the ids.

Comment: I agree. Although I've come up with a few ideas for a hacky fix, that's really not how I prefer to do things. Despite document.all not turning out to be the root issue, it's only a matter of time before the application breaks again anyways as our users adopt IE 10 and 11. I'll try a script to decode the entities and present some options to people who can actually make a decision on this, thanks.

Comment: Glad to help - if you can accept my answer I'll be able to feed my family for another month - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to leave the accepted answer as it is, but add this answer in case anyone else has issues with this in the future.

My circumstances changed and I was able to add a class to the project.  The class in my question:

```
public class HtmlAttributeEncodingNot : System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder
{
    protected override void HtmlAttributeEncode(string value, System.IO.TextWriter output)
    {
        output.Write(value);
    }
}
```

along with using the class for the encoding in the web.config:
`<httpRuntime encoderType="HtmlAttributeEncodingNot"/>`

was sufficient for dealing with the single quotes in `Attributes.Add` being encoded to `$#39;`

Additionally, something to look out for with old JavaScript is the way .net renders the ClientID of controls. Using a combination of the above code, along with `<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>` , and `clientIDMode="AutoID"`, I was able to render the html the same as it's 2.0 equivalent and solve my problem for the time being.